# Different performance creating tcpclient in Powershell (windows server 2012 vs windows 10)

Tags: windows, powershell

When I create a TcpClient in Powershell on a Win2012 R12 it is slower than the same command on Windows 10. I thought there was a network problem but I tried different computers with different configurations and I always get the same result.

These are the measures:

**Windows Server 2012 R2**

```
PS C:\Users\Code> Measure-Command { $client = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient -ArgumentList 172.17.8.53, 502 }


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 9
Milliseconds      : 34
Ticks             : 90340280
TotalDays         : 0,000104560509259259
TotalHours        : 0,00250945222222222
TotalMinutes      : 0,150567133333333
TotalSeconds      : 9,034028
TotalMilliseconds : 9034,028
```

**Windows 10**

```
PS C:\Users\Code> Measure-Command { $client = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient -ArgumentList 172.17.8.53, 502 }


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 10
Ticks             : 102308
TotalDays         : 1,18412037037037E-07
TotalHours        : 2,84188888888889E-06
TotalMinutes      : 0,000170513333333333
TotalSeconds      : 0,0102308
TotalMilliseconds : 10,2308
```

I launch procmon to find the problem but no chance. Any clue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are both PowerShell versions the same?

Comment: They are both PS 5.1

Comment: This can be based on alot of stuff... Obvious stuff. {Hardware, .net Framework version, Resource Usage based on other applications}

Comment: @Pepe If both PowerShell versions are the same try to make sure the points ArcSet mentioned are not the cause, if you not testing in like environments it's not going to be easy to find the cause.

Comment: It is the first thing we have thought. So we did tests on other computers and another network but we got the same result.

Comment: Did you put the server on lower hardware then windows 10? What Framework are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your help. The server hardware is not lower. We think the hardware can not make such a big difference: From 10 milliseconds to 9000 milliseconds.

Comment: I just review the framework. They are the same: 4.0.30319.42000